# disabling Java DNS cache

Tags: java, http, dns, network-programming, round-robin

I'm using Java 8 (OpenJDK). It seems like the best way to disable dns cache in Java is to set `networkaddress.cache.ttl=0` in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security`.

I've tried that, but it seems to have no effect, no matter what value I put there, DNS entries are cached for ~5 seconds. I know that the value is set properly because I check it with `java.security.Security.getProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl")`.

I'm testing the java cache with a `HttpURLConnection` client, and comparing it to a raw `curl` client, curl doesn't cache at all. My server is a load balancer that returns one of 3 different ips for each request in round robin. Those ips each host a web service that returns the hostname it's running on.

This is how the my java client looks like:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("networkaddress.cache.ttl=" + java.security.Security.getProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl"));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        printServerHost();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        printServerHost();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        printServerHost();
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        printServerHost();
        Thread.sleep(11000);
        printServerHost();
    }

    public static void printServerHost() throws Exception{
        URL url = new URL("http://server/");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        con.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String response = reader.readLine();
        reader.close();
        con.disconnect();

        System.out.println(response);
    }
```

Which outputs:

```
networkaddress.cache.ttl=0
ip-172-31-12-68.ec2.internal
ip-172-31-12-68.ec2.internal
ip-172-31-12-68.ec2.internal
ip-172-31-41-56.ec2.internal
ip-172-31-16-34.ec2.internal
```

And this is how my curl client looks like:

```
curl server
sleep 2s
curl server
sleep 4s
curl server
sleep 6s
curl server
sleep 11s
curl server
```

Which outputs:

```
ip-172-31-41-56.ec2.internal
ip-172-31-16-34.ec2.internal
ip-172-31-12-68.ec2.internal
ip-172-31-41-56.ec2.internal
ip-172-31-16-34.ec2.internal
```

What am I missing? Should I also configure something in `HttpURLConnection`? Another jvm wide config? Maybe it's another cache, not a dns one, a connection pool or a socket pool?

Answer (score -1):

Issue was another cache, not related to dns, probably in connection or socket, as using a `ForkJoinPool` shows different hosts:

```
ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(3);        
forkJoinPool.submit(() -> IntStream.range(0, 10).parallel().forEach(i -> printServerHost())).get();
```